# How to destroy session in PHP when browser back button is clicked?

Tags: php, session

I have read many related question here but seems not solve my problem. How to destroy session in PHP when user clicked at the browser back button.

Example, current page is home.php, when back button is clicked, it will go to index.php. So should be session will by destroy.

I trying both options. But still not destroy the session.

First Option (home.php)

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_destroy();
    }
?>
```

Second Option (index.php) This is not practical.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     window.history.forward();
</script>
```

Comment: `I have read many related question here` sadly we don't know what you've read or not.... `:-/`

Comment: Do you want to destroy the *whole* session or just a single variable?

Comment: Using the back button will most likely reload the page from the browsers cache. So unless you write some Javascript to watch for this event you may never know is has happened

Comment: @RiggsFolly Browsers will not cache the session like that. Even if it caches most of the page it will still send the cookie to the site and accept the response. Otherwise this would be a massive security hole for banking and other protect data.

Comment: @danielson317 can you explain that further? How do they work otherwise? Clicking the back button does not neccessarily issue a new request, so there is nothing sent to the server, not even a cookie

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't have the technical data just personal experience. I cache images for up to a week on my own web app. If I log out of the site you can no longer view the images even if you use the back button.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a reliable way to clear **all values** of any current session you can use this on the loading of any page where you want to remove session data:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ($criteria_for_session_deletion === true) {
    $_SESSION = []; // _SESSION is now an empty array
    }
```

This will remove any value from the superglobal. It will *not* change the identity of the superglobal, but that shouldn't be important if the variable is now empty.

---

It is unclear from your question but you may be having overlap issues with browser caching of the outputted HTML page. Please clarify exactly what you're trying to delete?

---

Clicking on a "back button" is a very problematical way of solving this concept and we really need some clarification from you as to what's *actually* going on.

If you have a user who needs to have session data removed then you should check this in PHP on a script before any outout is sent to the browser, and then triggering the above code when required.

You maybe should have a "validity check" script included in each page so every time one of these pages is loaded your "check script" is called, and deletes the session data when the deletion criteria is met.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How is the given code triggered when clicking the back button?

Comment: @NicoHaase I do not feel I can provide a more complete answer without the OP answering questions I/we have left in comments

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to destroy session? That is just irritating. I have seen such implementations in government/bank websites and it pretty much sucks.

Rather you should redirect the user to dashboard if the user is logged in.

**This doesn't directly answer OP's question but is a better way.**

Something like this:

```php
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
    header('Location: <dashboard-page>');
    exit;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't carry out their requested action, this simply sends them to another page. ...And it does that poorly.

Comment: What do you mean by poorly? and requested action?

Comment: header redirects should always be followed by `exit` statements to stop the script continuing.

Comment: The OP requested how to delete a session, your answer tells them how to load a dashboard page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ```exit```. I just advised this for better accessibility. Sometimes user unintentionally clicks on the back button and if that logs him/her out then that is not awesome.

Comment: Maybe not the answer the OP asked for but definitely the answer the OP needed.